# uniswap V2 invalid BigNumber value for JSBI negative value

Tags: javascript, ethereum

Hi I was following uniswapV2 document to perform a trade transaction and I encounter error as follow [invalid bignumber value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHyZX.png)

I got my input amount as 2941991120 and in JSBI form it is -1352976176, which gave me invalid bignumber value bug. Here is my code [code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ONbj.png). But I was following exactly what the tutorial says https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/javascript-SDK/trading/

Can anyone tell me where I did wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The example tells you the value should be converted to hex:

`const value = trade.inputAmount.raw // // needs to be converted to e.g. hex`

Same for one of the other values. Have you tried this?

If you use a (signed) integer, its sign can be positive/negative (`+`/`-`). Whatever value you're sending is deemed to be a negative one, which is unexpected and so the response is telling you.

This exmaple seems to suggest you can do: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87983/failed-transaction-error-encountered-during-contract-execution-on-uniswap-rout

```
...
const amountOutMinHex = ethers.BigNumber.from(amountOutMin.toString()).toHexString();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is unnecessarily complex.  The `JSBI::toString()` method takes a radix parameter, so [your linked example](https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/2.0.0/guides/trading) would simply look like:

```
trade.minimumAmountOut(slippageTolerance).raw.toString(16);
```